# Number Of Two Pair (Poker) Combinations Allowing For Pairs Or The "Junk" Card To Be Of The Same Rank

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, poker

The standard two pair formula is
${13\choose2}{11\choose1}{4\choose2}{4\choose2}{4\choose1}$
but this assumes that in the poker hand AABBC the rank of AA, BB and C cannot be the same (to avoid for conflicts with 4oak and full house).

I am trying to derive a formula which counts two pair combinations where the rank of AA can be equal to BB or the rank of AA/BB can be equal to C. For Example I'd like to count the poker hand 22223 as a two pair (two pairs of 2s) or the hand 22333 (a pair of 2s and a pair of 3s).

I had the idea to use the combinations w/ repetitions function for ${13\choose2}$ which I think properly accounts for the rank of AA to be equal to BB, but I'm pretty sure the final result of 144144 is still wrong because subtracting the number of 4oak/full house combinations doesn't result in 123552.

Thank you for your time reading this and any potential help.

Comment: Why not just add the number of possible 4oak and fh hands to your "2 pairs but nothing more" result?

Comment: I am trying to make the game of poker except where the user can augment certain aspects of the game like which poker hands to play with or how many ranks/suits to use. Adding the 4oak and fh totals to the two pair would only give me the result for a 5 card poker hand with a standard 52 card deck when ultimately I am after a dynamic formula that can account for many variables.